# Cómo agregar strings a una lista enlazada en lenguaje C

Tags: c, string, lista

Necesito que el usuario inserte un nombre y que éste se vaya almacenando en una lista enlazada.

Hasta ahora llevo esto:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct lista {
    int valor;
    char *nombre;
    lista * prox;
};
void agregarstr(lista**p,char* name){
   lista * t;
    if (!p) {
      (*p)-> prox = NULL;
      (*p)-> nombre = name;
    } else {
      t = (struct lista * ) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
      t->valor= t;
      t-> prox = *p; *p = t;
    }

int main() {
  char name[50];
  lista * p = NULL;
  printf("indique el nombre");
  fflush(stdin);
  get(name);      
  agregarstr(&p,name);
  break;
  printf("el nombre es %s",p->nombre);
  return 0;
}
```

Pero no tuve éxito con lo que fui intentando.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!p) {
  (*p)-> prox = NULL;
  (*p)-> nombre = name;
}
```

Ya empiezas mal. Según ese código, si `p==NULL`, es decir, si `p` **no está incializado** entonces intentes acceder a su contenido. Te sobra la negación del `if`:

```
if (p) {
  (*p)-> prox = NULL;
  (*p)-> nombre = name;
} else {
```

Aunque si te parece un poco confuso siempre puedes hacer la comparación explícita:

```
if (p != NULL) {
  (*p)-> prox = NULL;
  (*p)-> nombre = name;
} else {
```

Aunque claro, si se supone que la función pretende añadir un elemento a la lista entonces debería crear un nuevo elemento **siempre**. Se me ocurre algo tal que:

```
lista * t = calloc(1,sizeof(lista));
t->nombre = name;

if( *p==NULL )
  *p = t; // el nuevo nodo es el primer elemento de la lista
else
{
  // El nuevo nodo se añade al final de la lista
  Lista* nodo = *p;
  while( nodo->prox ) nodo = nodo->prox;
  nodo->prox = t; 
}
```

Por otro lado tienes que ser consciente de que `(*p)-> nombre = name;` no está duplicando la cadena sino únicamente copiando el puntero. Si la dirección de memoria apuntada por `name` la reutilizas para otras cadenas vas a perder información en todos los nodos:

```
char name[50];
strcpy(name,"a");
nodo* n1 = calloc(1,sizeof(lista));
n1->nombre=name;

strcpy(name,"b");
nodo* n2 = calloc(1,sizeof(lista));
n2->nombre = name;

printf("%s %s",n1->nombre,n2->nombre);
```

Para evitar esto tienes que hacer una reserva de memoria y copiar la cadena de caracteres:

```
lista * t = calloc(1,sizeof(lista));
//t->nombre = name; <<-- Ya no sirve

// opcion 1
t->nombre = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
strcpy(t->nombre,name);

// opcion 2
t->nombre = strdup(name);
```

Por otro lado...

```
t->valor= t;
```

Si `t` es la estructura y `t->valor` es de tipo entero está claro que esa instrucción está mal. No se qué esperas almacenar en `valor`, pero debería ser un entero y no un puntero.